# chef: How do I increase the CommandTimout for Mixlib::ShellOut in a ruby block?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to perform a database data load in a chef recipe on an Ubuntu 14.04 system with a Chef 11.10.4 based client.  I'm doing the data load in a ruby block and here are the relevant portions of the error in the log:

> Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout
>
> Command timed out after 600s:
>
> Command exceeded allowed execution time, killed by TERM signal.
>
> [2015-10-06T01:24:00+00:00] ERROR: ruby_block[Load Dataset] (chef-virtuoso::load line 178) had an error:
> Mixlib::ShellOut::CommandTimeout: Command timed out after 600s:

Anyone know how to increase the default CommandTimeout to 3600 for a `shell_out!` in a ruby block?

Here is the ruby block from the recipe that is failing:

```
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)

ruby_block "Load Dataset" do
  block do
    shell_out!(DATA_LOAD_COMMAND)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mixlib-shellout code](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout/blob/master/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb#L93) and chef mixin [shell_out code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb#L32) you should be able to use the `timeout` option like this:

```
ruby_block "Load Dataset" do
  block do
    shell_out!(DATA_LOAD_COMMAND, :timeout => 3600)
  end
end
```

You don't have to send the Class into Recipe, it's already part of the DSL.